# Using protractor spyOn() for jQuery ajax() cause error "ajax() method does not exist"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, protractor

I trying to test the ajax is used to form submit. The protractor code for test is:

```
describe('login.php', function() {

it("should use ajax on submit", function() {
  browser.get('/login.php');
  spyOn($, "ajax");
  $("form#frmLogin [type='submit']").click();
  expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
});
```

it fails with the message:

```
Error: ajax() method does not exist
```

What is wrong?

Other tests are going well. It's Windows PC. Protractor conf:

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

  specs: [
    'e2e/*.js',
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        args: ['--test-type']
    }
  },

  chromeOnly: true,

  baseUrl: 'http://mysite.local/',

  framework: 'jasmine',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

Is something wrong with my environment?

Comment: Are you able to access `$`?

Comment: It seems like spyOn() doesn't have access to window object and to ajax $. But the next line using $ to emulate click working well.

Comment: If you pass the `$` reference to `spyOn` I don't see how it couldn't access the `ajax` property. Do you spy on `$.ajax` from several tests? If so do you restore the `$.ajax` method?

Comment: No, it's only test so no need to restore `$.ajax` method.

Comment: It's best to restore the spy anyway, you could forget to do it before testing `$.ajax` elsewhere. What does `console.log($.ajax);` output?

Comment: Well you got your issue, I think jQuery is not even loaded. You should be able to access `$.ajax` directly (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aymericbeaumet/kh2gfrnw/)). What does `console.log($)` and `console.log(jQuery);` output?

Comment: could it be, that protractor interprets `$` as [protractors $](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#api-elementfinder-prototype-%24) ... just guessing, i'm not familiar with ajax and protractor ;)

Comment: console.log($) = [Function]; console.log(jQuery) = jQuery is not defined; console.log($.ajax) = undefined;

Answer (score 2):

You cannot spy on jQuery because it is defined in your browser, not in your protractor test. Your protractor test is a node process that runs outside of the browser. It uses the webdriver protocol to communicate with the browser.

I would recommend you to write a unit test in karma for this scenario.

Comment: So I can not test ajax at protractor at all?

Comment: You can assert that the current url has changed after login. You can also test that there is a logout link. What would a user see after login? That would be a good way to test.